# Why won't this batch code for my game work?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been having a bit of fun with batch coding and stuff, I have been making a little text adventure game with multiple choices and endings. At a certain point, you can choose to become the president.

```
:lvl1
cls
color 0a
echo You awake in a dark room.
echo What do you do?
echo.
echo 1) Take the nearest torch.
echo 2) Do nothing.
echo 3) Become the president.
echo 4) Wait, isn't this exactly like The Adventure 1?
set /p answer=

if %answer% == 1 goto lvl2-1
if %answer% == 2 goto bordem
if %answer% == 3 goto presidency
if %answer% == 4 goto yes
```

Basically I had a little inside joke here since this is the sequel, and it's kind of the same opening.
So you can choose the president option, this is the code for it.

```
:presidency
cls
color 0a
echo You decided to become the President
echo What do you do now?
echo.
echo 1) RAISE TAXES!
echo 2) MAKE A SPEECH!
echo 3) NOTHING!
echo 4) DECREASE TAXES!
set /p answer=

if %answer% == 1 goto really?
if %answer% == 2 goto speech
if %answer% == 3 goto uselesspresident
if %answer% == 4 goto thankyouforthat
```

Now, you should be able to choose the third option, and it would bring you to one of the endings.
But I tried doing that in the batch version, but I see a flash of the uselesspresident screen and then it puts me back to the first level (lvl1).
Here's the code for uselesspresident:

```
:uselesspresident
cls
color 0a
echo You did nothing as the president.
echo Worst. President. Ever.
echo Achievement unlocked!: Lazy ass.
echo USELESS PRESIDENT ENDING
echo Play more?
echo (y/n)
set /p answer=

if %answer% == y goto lvl1
if %answer% == n goto menu
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code, maybe one of you can?
I haven't tested all of my game yet, so if I come across any more coding problems, I'll post it to this forum.
Thank you if you can find the problem.

EDIT: I've figured it out.
I can't believe I didn't think of it sooner, but here goes.
I was editing from the text file, and not the batch itself when I realised this:

```
echo (y/n)
set /p answer

if %answer% == y goto lvl1
if %answer% == n goto menu
```

This is what it was BEFORE I fixed it up, so I added the = sign and fixed it up then saved.
But I didn't export it as the .bat, so the .bat was still the same but the text file was edited.
I really need to remember to EDIT the .bat file instead of editing the text file separately.

Comment: A simple test of y/n Works fine for me (winXP). I would suggest commenting out any `cls`, and enabling `echo on` as the first thing you do in `:uselesspresident`. It may hint at what's going on. Alternatively, do you have CAPS-LOCK on? `Y != y`, so you may need to test for `Y` and `N` also.

Comment: Before every `set /p answer=` put this to initialise the variable `set "answer="`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the issue is the case of the entered value, you could try replacing the test with something like the following:

```
echo (y/n)
set /p answer=
if /I %answer% EQU y echo yes
if /I %answer% EQU n echo no
```

Of course replace the `echo`'s with your `goto` statements.  This makes the assumption that Command Extensions are enabled (which they should be by default), and basically performs a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if %answer% == "y" goto lvl1
if %answer% == "n" goto menu
```

Comment: That would only match if the user typed `"y"` or `"n"` at the prompt... at least it does for me. It doesn't match for just typing `y` or `n`.

Comment: I think, he meant `if "%answer%" == "y" goto ...`.